# Reordering an aggregated stars object

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I'm performing temporal aggregations on netcdf rasters using the stars package in R. Typically the objects have (X, Y, Time) dimensions and, after doing the temporal averages, get an object with dimensions ordered as (Time, X, Y). How would one go about changing the order of the dimensions back to the original order (X, Y, T)?

I've been searching through the package vignettes and the likely function examples for a method, but haven't had any luck. I feel like I'm probably missing something simple and obvious...

Here's a reprex:

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Warning: package 'abind' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.0.4
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
x = read_stars(c(tif, tif, tif), along = "band")
x
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:
#>   L7_ETMs.tif    
#>  Min.   : 47.00  
#>  1st Qu.: 65.00  
#>  Median : 76.00  
#>  Mean   : 77.34  
#>  3rd Qu.: 87.00  
#>  Max.   :255.00  
#> dimension(s):
#>      from  to  offset delta                       refsys point values x/y
#> x       1 349  288776  28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [x]
#> y       1 352 9120761 -28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [y]
#> band    1  18      NA    NA                           NA    NA   NULL

time = as.Date("2021-03-24") + 1:18
x = st_set_dimensions(x, "band", values = time)

y = aggregate(x, by = "3 days", "mean")
y
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>   L7_ETMs.tif    
#>  Min.   :  5.00  
#>  1st Qu.: 56.67  
#>  Median : 71.67  
#>  Mean   : 68.91  
#>  3rd Qu.: 84.00  
#>  Max.   :255.00  
#> dimension(s):
#>      from  to     offset  delta                       refsys point values x/y
#> time    1   6 2021-03-25 3 days                         Date    NA   NULL    
#> x       1 349     288776   28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [x]
#> y       1 352    9120761  -28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [y]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple and I should have known it! Because stars objects are, in part, a list of arrays, the dimensions can be reordered using aperm in the same way you would with a normal n-dimensionsal array.

```r
aperm(y, c(2, 3, 1))
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>   L7_ETMs.tif    
#>  Min.   :  5.00  
#>  1st Qu.: 56.67  
#>  Median : 71.67  
#>  Mean   : 68.91  
#>  3rd Qu.: 84.00  
#>  Max.   :255.00  
#> dimension(s):
#>      from  to     offset  delta                       refsys point values x/y
#> x       1 349     288776   28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [x]
#> y       1 352    9120761  -28.5 UTM Zone 25, Southern Hem... FALSE   NULL [y]
#> time    1   6 2021-03-25 3 days                         Date    NA   NULL
```